# A minimum/maximum problem using the point of inflection

Tags: calculus, optimization, related-rates

If I had an equation $F(t)$ = $t$ $e^{\frac{-t}{10}}$ that modelled the concentration of a chemical with respect to time (where $t$ represented time in minutes).

1. If I wanted to find the time when the concentration of the drug decreased at the fastest rate, why would that be where the point of inflection is?
2. How would I find the time when the rate of increase was a maximum?

For reference:

I found $F'(t)$ = $e^{\frac{-t}{10}}$ ($\frac{-t}{10}$ +1)

And I found $F''(t)$ = $e^{\frac{-t}{10}}$ ($\frac{t}{100}$ - $\frac{1}{5}$)

Comment: Someone from the future:  I read your book 1984...  really amazing insight.

Comment: Anyway, you want to find maximum of first derivative.  So, you should definitely check inflection point (where F'' = 0).

Comment: Questions (1) and (2) are a 2-apples-3-pears way to ask for, respectively, the minimum and maximum of $F'$. And then the reasoning is clear.

Comment: Is the function $F$ modeling the concentration of the chemical, or the rate of change of the concentration of the chemical? "Model[ing] how much the concentration of a chemical changed over time" seems kind of ambiguous. I assume it's probably the former.

Comment: @ilikemath The question is "The concentration of a chemical changes according to F where t is time in minutes".

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think I understand how question (1) works, but I'm struggling to find the reasoning for it as there was only one point found and it was a minimum.